# How do i set expiration on CSS, JS and Images for windows server

Tags: windows, server, web-config, mod-expires, expires-header

How do i set expiration on CSS, JS and Images for windows server

Comment: Where are you setting that? Apache? In your htaccess? How is that related to PHP? You really need to clarify your question. If it is Apache/htaccess, you can read more here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_expires.html

Comment: 1) yes i use apache server.  2) I use google web page test in that it shows below errors (http://www.clearskin.in/additional-css/medic/style.css (expiration not specified)
http://www.clearskin.in/css/animations.css (expiration not specified)) How I fix this

Comment: Then remove all other tags and just add `Apache`. Also, did you read the manual for the `mod_expires` I linked to? Did you try anything? If yes, show us what you tried. If no, try something. I did a quick google search and found multiple extensive guides, examples and tutorials about this. Please do some research before posting.

Comment: I use google web page tester and I found below error http://www.clearskin.in/additional-css/medic/style.css (expiration not specified)  I dont know how to set expiration for css, js, img

Comment: FYI. I changed the tags to more relevant ones.

Comment: ok thanks but what the sol for this expiration css js and img files

Comment: Like I said, doing a Google search on something like "expiresdefault css js" gives you several examples/guides. Here's one link: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/5265/how-do-i-set-expiration-headers-for-css-js-and-images